# Does intern supports angularjs selectors a-la-protractor?

Tags: protractor, intern

I'm trying to decide whether to use intern or protractor for my e2e test with SauceLabs, and I find really helpful these "by"s that protractor provides (by.model, by.binding, by.repeater) and I was wondering if such locator strategies are also possible to use in intern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protractor uses the WebDriverJS library, not the WD.js library, so it is not likely to be directly compatible, but the idea behind how Protractor works would be possible just as well in Intern by writing the same kinds of helper functions that Protractor provides:

```js
define([ 'intern!tdd', 'tests/support/locators' ], function (tdd, locators) {
  tdd.suite('suite', function () {
    tdd.test('test', function () {
      var remote = this.remote;
      remote.get('http://example.com')
        .then(locators.by.model('foo'))
        .then(function (model) {})
        // ...etc
        ;
    });
  });
```

Where, in the above, `locators.by.model` is a method like:

```js
function model(modelId) {
  return this.execute(function () {
    return document.querySelectorAll(['ng-model=' + modelId + ']');
  });
}
```

EDIT: You can also use Protractor’s `clientsidescripts` module directly:

```js
define([ 'intern!tdd', 'intern/dojo/node!protractor/lib/clientsidescripts' ], function (tdd, scripts) {
  tdd.suite('suite', function () {
    tdd.test('test', function () {
      var remote = this.remote;
      remote.get('http://example.com')
        .execute(scripts.findByModel, [ 'foo' ])
        .then(function (model) {})
        // ...etc
        ;
    });
  });
```

Comment: So given that, any reason why to use intern over protractor?

Comment: Because of all [the other features](https://github.com/theintern/intern#comparison) that Intern provides that Protractor does not: AMD test modules, async using promises, different test interfaces, different reporters, better component integration, etc.

Comment: As it turns out, Protractor exposes the client-side scripts it uses to pull elements from the DOM as a separate module, so you can just pass those functions directly to `execute`. I have updated the answer above with additional information.